# Not able to see Account Team related list in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

In sales force lightning I am able to see the "Opportunity Teams" related list in Opportunity page. But not be able to see the "Account Team" related list in Account page. I came to know that this is the limitation of Lightning experience based on release notes of winter'16 and spring'16.

Is there any other feasibility to accomplish this?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling it'll be in the summer release, if you take a look at the roadmap [here](http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/lightning/#Roadmap). It's on the list for upcoming features:
[image: Lightning Roadmap]